# How to use variable in template match xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to use variable in template match in xslt but I transformed template match into variable.  I got syntax error.

This is my orginal xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/name/name[not(telephoneNav/detail/action = 'A') and not(telephoneNav/detail/action = 'S')]"/>
<xsl:template match="detail[not(action = 'A') and not(action = 'S')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my xslt which has been transformed into variable in template match.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
      <xsl:variable name="actionXpath1" select="'/name/name[not(telephoneNav/detail/action = &apos;A&apos;) and not(telephoneNav/detail/action = &apos;S&apos;)]'" />
      <xsl:variable name="actionXpath2" select="'detail[not(action = &apos;A&apos;) and not(action = &apos;S&apos;)]'" />
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="$actionXpath1"/>
      <xsl:template match="$actionXpath2"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

like this https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiw

Comment: Variables store values (string values in your examples), not match patterns or other XPath expressions. -- P.S. Please choose either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Like this https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiw

Comment: Not sure what I am supposed to learn from that. In XSLT 1.0, *"It is an error for the value of the `match` attribute to contain a VariableReference."* In XSLT 2.0 your attempt cannot work for other reasons, as I explained earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 using static parameters and `_match` as a shadow attribute you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">
  <xsl:param name="actionXpath1" static="yes" select="'/name/name[not(telephoneNav/detail/action = &quot;A&quot;) and not(telephoneNav/detail/action = &quot;S&quot;)]'" />
  <xsl:param name="actionXpath2" static="yes" select="'detail[not(action = &quot;A&quot;) and not(action = &quot;S&quot;)]'" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template _match="{$actionXpath1}"/>
  <xsl:template _match="{$actionXpath2}"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiw/1

So you need to use an XSLT 3 processor and you need to use it in a way that allows setting static parameters, i.e. use an API specialized for XSLT 3 to support setting such parameters before the stylesheet is compiled.